# Butchering a String word wise

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to separate a long string into each words and print them sequentially in Java but it throws exception `StringIndexOutOfBounds`. Heres the code, any input is highly appreciated:

```
public class SpellingChecker {
public static void test(String str) {
    int i=0,j=0,n=str.length();
    String temp="";
    do{
        for(i=j;str.charAt(i)!=' ';i++)
            temp+=str.charAt(i);
        temp+='\0';
        System.out.println(temp);
        temp="";
        j=i+1;
    }while(j<n);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter string for which you want to check spelling : ");
    String strng=input.next();
    test(strng);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain your do while in test function?

Comment: this code is doing something different than desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `next()` instead of `nextLine()` to scan for your sentence. So you will be only getting the first word instead of all the words..

So change it to

```
String strng = input.nextLine();
```

Next on your `test()` method this should be the template

```
public static void test(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
    for(String word: words) {
        System.out.println(word);
        //Here decide what you want to do with each word
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one. Your code is absolutely okay yet I managed to keep up my "caveman" version by adding a space before taking in the entire string,i.e,
`str+=' ';` before editing it in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want:

```
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : words)
    temp.append(word).append("\0");
```

Comment: It's best not to `+=` strings inside of loops: it becomes an `O(n²)` operation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. This is ver 0.1 so I didn't even think about complexity scenarios. Will definitely take care in future.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thanks, I changed it to use a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you could rewrite `test(String)` to use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with something like,

```
public static void test(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=j;str.charAt(i)!=' ';i++)
temp+=str.charAt(i);
```

i think this go out of range if the string doesn't have any space in it